Fetch table names using regexp
Need to fetch tablename from input using sql query.I know this can be done through regex but not sure how hence any help appreciated
Input:



Field1
field2




a
INSERT INTO test.table2{ name, age, city, id}SELECT name, age, city, id FROM table 1


b
select from test1.table3


c
select *from test2.table4


d
select *from test2.table4(10)



Output:



Field1
field2




a
test.table2


b
test1.table3


c
test2.table4




For a general solution, you would need a SQL parser, not just regex.  I suggest that you insert the table name into a new column at the same time you insert the raw SQL.

Btw, postgres 9 is no longer maintained since 3 years. You should strongly consider upgrading.

@TimBiegeleisen-I can add other column but if you can please help with SQL parser/regex that will give me an idea how to write it as I am new to postgres.

@Bergi-I have used it as tag to reach out but we are already using upgraded version.Can you pls help/give an idea how to write this query.Thank you

@Ram A SQL parser is a very large and complex piece of software. Here you can see how much PostgreSQL has to do before it starts figuring out which one out of nine things you're selecting from. Identifying it as an insert/update/delete/merge target takes some work too, and a table name could also be perfectly valid as a value/expression in the select list, a condition, as a function argument, among other places. It will be difficult™ to re-implement all that in a regex.

@Zegarek-There are 4 cases insert,update,delete and select.So those need to be handled.Is there any sample query that you can help with to start.I can refine it further.

@Zegarek-I have added few more comments to see if its possible to replace single and double quotes in string while doing regexp match and just keep it in beginning and end so that the scope of false positive will be less..I have tried it but its not working.I have given code in comment if you can pls advise if something needs to be modified.

It will be extremely difficult to achieve with just a regular expression. If you really need to do that reliably, you can check out how pgpool-II re-used PostgreSQL's own parser for their needs - that's more of a C++ intensive task, rather than a SQL one.
Here are some more examples at the wiki, some of which you can use directly. You could even get Python sqlparse to process the query text, then .get_identifiers(), all inside the db, in a PL/Python function.
If you only wish to cover some very basic cases, you can try to target tokens following certain keywords:
select field1
  ,unnest(
      regexp_matches(
         field2
        ,'(?:UPDATE|INTO|FROM|JOIN|USING|TABLE)(?:\s+ONLY)*\s+([[:alpha:]_]+[[:word:]]*|"[^"]+")'
        ,'gi'
      )
   ) AS spotted_table
from table1;




field1
spotted_table




a
table2


a
table1


b
table3


c
table4




The ?: in (?:something) makes the parentheses non-capturing, which is why it only reports matches from the last group that doesn't have the ?:
the g in 'gi' makes this report all matches, and i disables case-sensitivity
the identifier syntax is taken from the doc, except the $ oddity:

SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (a-z, but also letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore (_). Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be letters, underscores, digits (0-9), or dollar signs ($)



That list of keywords is by no means exhaustive, and while it covers your examples, this regular expression is extremely brittle. See some obvious blind spots in this demo.
It gets more and more tricky if you consider

identifiers can be double-quoted or unquoted, which makes them fold to lowercase
single or dollar-quoted string constants that contain SQL-looking text - useful if you're also considering dynamic SQL, otherwise it would get you false positives
technically, you can name a table "select from table7 join TABLE8 on waitaminute;" (this whole thing is the name of the table, not just the table7 part): demo
long, comma-separated lists of relations interleaved with sources that aren't relations, especially subqueries
end of line // and in-line/multi-line /*...*/ comments

If the queries you're analysing operate on the same database you keep them in, you can correlate that with information_schema.tables. Note that there are 9 different things that can be in that same spot in the body of a query, and that's not counting the fact that table is just one form of one of those, a relation. You can also select from a view, materialized view, foreign table, partitioned table, all of which act like a table only to some extent. Some views are updatable, which means you can also insert/merge/update/delete from them as if you interacted with their underlying table directly.
If you're trying to track effective interactions, you'd have to also track the rule and trigger systems, view and matview definitions as well as routine bodies and dependencies.

@zegarek-Thanks for the information and giving me starting point..Yes,I need only the basic one...I have used your sql and its giving me good results however,there are few points where its not working correctly...example if in case we have multiple tables then need to be one row with multiple tables in comma seperated value. Other one is I need to fetch target table in most of the cases not source ....cases where we have select *from tablename in those cases only I need to fetch tablename,if its insert,update,delete in those case focus is only to fetch target tablename.

@Ram What you're listing, I already demonstrated in the "obvious blind spots in this demo" in the answer above. I'm not proposing this as the requested regex-based parser, my point is that while regular expressions do seem like they're perfectly capable of all this, in reality it gets very messy, very quickly, to a point you're really better off spending time trying to integrate an actual, proper parser, instead of trying to re-implement one from scratch with an ill-suited tool. :)

That being said, I'll see if the lists can be added and exactly how ugly this will get. EDIT: after re-reading your comment I realised you just want to aggregate the results and keep the targets separate from sources whenever there's an insert/update/delete. That's pretty easy: demo. The bigger problem is that the regex currently doesn't like comma-separated lists of relations (old-style implicit join syntax), quoting, aliasing, subqueries, etc.

Thank you @Zegarek-I have added one more case in fiddle but looks like its not working..https://dbfiddle.uk/n2F-PmKD.I have run it in db also with code but throwing ERROR: invalid regular expression: invalid character class

sql : SELECT field1, unnest(regexp_matches(field1, '(?:FROM|JOIN|USING|TABLE)(?:\s+ONLY)\s+([[:alpha:]_]+.[[:word:]]|"[^"]+")','gi')) from test.table1  but getting error :  invalid regular expression: invalid character class.I have search on google but wanted to check is it require any escape character removal?

Is it possible wherever we are have false positive in demo ,if we remove the quotes first and keep it just in starting and in end to get correct result.I am trying to implement it but its not working as expected because it looks like string also contain select thats why . select field1 ,regexp_matches(concat(''''||replace (field1,'''','')||'''') ,'(?:UPDATE|INTO)(?:\s+ONLY)\s+([[:alpha:]_]+[[:word:]]|"[^"]+")'
,'gi'
)from tablename

@Ram Here are some more examples of how it's done. Again: this answer was supposed to serve as an argument against doing what you're now trying to do, demonstrating why it's not really a good idea to try that with a simple regex. You can use Python sqlparse to process the query text, then .get_identifiers(), in a PL/Python function.

Bottom line is: it's hard, it's even harder with just a regex, but most importantly it's already been done multiple times. You really are better off using one of the readily available, well-tested and documented solutions.
